# LXD 2.0 on Debian 8.4

Tags: debian, virtualization, lxc, containers

I'm running Debian 8.4 and would like to set-up recently released LXD 2.0. Is this feasible, or should I stick with LXC? It seems all focus is on using LXD with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

If stuff is not in the repos of your desired distro but you still want to run applications/services on top of it, you are in for trouble (read: extra work to keep things running at all) sooner or later.

If things are different (because-you-know-what-you-are-doing(tm)), you will know wheter a technology is safe to use for you or not.

For now you should stick with Ubuntu if you really want LXD to use it as a  frontend to LXC. (Because that's what LXD is, a frontend to LXC.)

If you just need containers, but still want to stick  with debian, use LXC directly. Proxmox is based on Debian, and you have LXC support there, too, which might very likely be the best approach for you, considering the maturity of the proxmox project.

If you want LXD for unprivileged containers in debian, try this with LXC: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-kernel-70/lxc-unprivileged-container-in-debian-jessie-cgroups-permissions-4175540174/

Answer (score 0):

The only real trouble I had was in building the packages for Debian. With the packages built, everything is working very fine, both on Jessie and Stretch.

Compiling the packages from source (using `debuild`) can be a bit cumbersome because you may need to handle dependencies available in Ubuntu but not Debian. This can be achieved (for a test system of course) by tweaking LXD's build configuration to use embedded Go packages, instead of looking them up in the repositories. IIRC, this setting is called `USE_EMBEDDED`.

Other than that, the packages will build fine for Jessie, and work without any trouble so far. The thing you really don't want to do is to try install LXD packages built for Ubuntu, because of the dependency differences